# bash: rename files in indeterminate sub-subfolders based on grandparent directory name

Tags: macos, bash, directory, batch-rename

Bash newbie here trying to insert the name of a folder into certain files inside that folder.

The problem is that these files are in subfolders of subfolders of the main directory, and the names of each level are different in each case.

For example, the main folder `interviews` may contain `John Doe` and under `John Doe` is a directory `Images` with a file `Screenshot.jpg`. But there might also be `John Smith` with a folder `Etc` in which is `12_Screenshot 2.jpg`.

I want to rename all these files containing `Screenshot` inserting `John Doe` or `John Smith` before the filename.

I tried adapting a couple of scripts I found and ran them from the `interviews` directory:

```
for i in `ls -l | egrep '^d'| awk '{print $10}'`; do  find . -type f -name "*Screenshot*" -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${i}${0}"' '{}' \; done
```

after which the terminal gives the caret prompt, as if I'm missing something. I also tried

```
find -regex '\./*' -type d -exec mv -- {}/*/*Screenshot* {}/{}.jpg \; -empty -delete
```

which returns `find: illegal option -- r`

The fact that the second one theoretically moves the file up to the parent folder is not a problem since I'll have to do this eventually anyways.

Comment: so you want `interviews/John Doe/images/Screenshot.jpg` -> `interviews/John Doe/images/John Doe-Screenshot.jpg`?

Comment: I think you might be missing a `;` after the `\;` in the first attempt. But you shouldn't parse the output of `ls` anyway.

Comment: @MarcB exactly. @EtanReisner I tried `for i in $( ls ); do  find . -type f -name "*Screenshot*" -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${i}${0}"' '{}' \; ; done`. It executes but has no effect. `i` seems to be empty in the mv string.

Comment: that is because you have it in single quotes = no substitution

Comment: @Ionewasp The mv command, or the brackets?

Comment: @fvogel your -exec part is wrong for me in many ways, so I'm touching only ${i} substitution. For ${i} to be substituted correctly it needs to be out of single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will work as desired :

```
dir=$1
find $dir -name "*Screenshot*" -type f | while read file
do
    base=$(basename $file)
    dirpath=$(dirname $file)
    extr=$(echo $file | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-2)}') #extracts the grandparent directory
    mv $file $dirpath/$extr-$base
done
```

As @loneswap mentioned, this must be invoked as a script. So if your main directory is `mainDir`, then you would invoke it as so...

```
./script mainDir
```

Comment: Error returned: `find: illegal option -- n`. Which doesn't make sense because it looks fine.

Comment: @fvogel You need to invoke this as a script passing one argument of directory to process

Comment: @lonewasp I should have looked closer. Works like a charm!

Comment: @Bolboa nice solution! could you suggest how to move renamed files to a new location, while leaving the original files unchanged

Comment: I figured it out (rename and copy to new location): add `dst = $1` in line 2 and `cp $dirpath/$extr-$base $dst` in the last line

Answer (score 0):

For each directory in current working directory, recursively find files containing string "screenshot" (case insensitive due to OSX). Split the found path into parent part (always present at least in form './') and file name, produce two lines one original file path, second one original folder + modified target file name. Execute mv command via xargs using two arguments (separate by newline to allow whitespaces in paths):

```
for i in `ls -l | sed -n '/^d\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\+\([^[:space:]]\+\)$/s//\2/p'`; do
    find "$i" -type f -iname "*Screenshot*" \
        | sed -n '\!^\(\([^/]\+/\)\+\)\([^/]\+\)$!s!!\1\3\n\1'$i'\3!p' \
        | xargs -d '\n' -n 2 mv;
done
```

Drawback: xargs on OSX does not know --no-run-if-empty, so for directories that do not contain files with "screenshot" string empty mv is invoked. Proper option needs to be added (don't have access to OSX man pages) or xargs ... 2>&/dev/null to ignore all errors...

Comment: try replacing my sed after egrep with yours awk call, in my case (Ubuntu/bash) ls -l gives less then 10 components and my intent was to get last one.

Comment: also try adding echo before mv to see which commands would be invoked

Comment: Replacing `sed '...'\` ;` with `awk '{print $10}'\`` I get:
`~/Desktop/interviews/interview_name ~/Desktop/interviews ~/Desktop/test
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
~/Desktop/interviews ~/Desktop/test`

Comment: With echo I get the line `mv ./images/The_Screenshot_12.jpg` in the middle of the output.

Comment: any whitespaces in paths?

Comment: Nope, the file I'm testing with is ".../Desktop/interviews/interview_name/images/The_Screenshot_12.jpg"

Comment: @fvogel try edited one in answer - I've made sed regex non-greedy, might help

Comment: As it is it had no effect, and with `awk` substituted it returned `xargs: illegal option -- -
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]`

Comment: @fvogel looks like your xargs don't understand --no-run-if-empty option, so in my last edit you would need to tolerate complains form empty mv invocations. Try Bolboa answer, though you might need to encapsulate $var references into double quotes (") if you have whitespaces in paths.

Comment: Mind to explain the solution?

Comment: @lonewasp Now it doesn't return errors, but it has no effect. It must be something with my system. Bolboa's answer worked for me.